How to fix the error IHttpClientFactory not exist when using open ai in unity3d?
the error is at line number 38
on the last line in this part of code:
public IHttpClientFactory HttpClientFactory { get; set; }

the full part:
using OpenAI_API.Audio;
using OpenAI_API.Chat;
using OpenAI_API.Completions;
using OpenAI_API.Embedding;
using OpenAI_API.Files;
using OpenAI_API.Images;
using OpenAI_API.Models;
using OpenAI_API.Moderation;
using System.Net.Http;

namespace OpenAI_API
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Entry point to the OpenAPI API, handling auth and allowing access to the various API endpoints
    /// </summary>
    public class OpenAIAPI : IOpenAIAPI
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Base url for OpenAI
        /// for OpenAI, should be "https://api.openai.com/{0}/{1}"
        /// for Azure, should be "https://(your-resource-name.openai.azure.com/openai/deployments/(deployment-id)/{1}?api-version={0}"
        /// </summary>
        public string ApiUrlFormat { get; set; } = "https://api.openai.com/{0}/{1}";

        /// <summary>
        /// Version of the Rest Api
        /// </summary>
        public string ApiVersion { get; set; } = "v1";

        /// <summary>
        /// The API authentication information to use for API calls
        /// </summary>
        public APIAuthentication Auth { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Optionally provide an IHttpClientFactory to create the client to send requests.
        /// </summary>
        public IHttpClientFactory HttpClientFactory { get; set; }

the full script i put in a link because it's a bit long:  https://pastebin.com/mrmq72Pp

See https://www.reddit.com/r/dotnetcore/comments/14isbia/how_do_i_use_ihttpclientfactory_in_a_class_library/

IHttpClientFactory is from .NET Platform Extensions .. which is not available in Unity => Whatever library you are using there is not made for Unity but "normal" .NET applications

@jdweng I think this one would be more accurate for OP's question ;) https://www.reddit.com/r/Unity3D/comments/14iqsxf/i_cant_fix_this_typenamespace_error_with/

You will need PackageReference to Microsoft.Extensions.Http.

The Interface IHttpClientFactory is from Microsoft.Extensions.Http, so you will need to include this Package Reference.
